# WinAPI saving results from multiple processes to one file

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, multiprocessing

I tried to search for similar questions but not found any.
As the issue is complicated to understand, will try to explain it again as easy as possible.
Basically, I have 3 c++ source file:

**1.MainProcess3args.cpp** - is executing 2 processes synchronized with mutex, second and third file is ran with `CreateProcess()` function. Process2 should always run first, and that part works ok. This file is receiving 3 arguments - 1st is how many numbers needs to be generated, second one is time distance between running processes and third one argument defines, how many times processes has to be excecuted. As example `MainProcess.exe 2 5 2` ,

**first argument 2** -how many number generate,

**second argument 5**- time distance in seconds between next number generating and caclulating average,minimum,maximum

**third argument 2** - how many times we will generate numbers and calculate average,min and max.

**2.Random.cpp** is generating N random values given as parameter and saving them to a RandomValues.txt file.

**3.ReadingRandoms.cpp** has 3 Threads- to calculate average, find minimum and maximum of numbers stored in a RandomValues.txt file.

I want to save to a new txt file information about given arguments to the file and system info and to save each results of average value, minimum and maximum, the file should look as following:

```
Total numbers: 2 | Version:Multithreads | Machine: OEM ID: 9 Processor Type: 8664 | Replies: 2 | Pause: 5
AVG     MIN    MAX
value1 value2 value3
values from next numbers generating...
```

I have 3 source files, tried with many combinations with loops `for(int i=0;i<argument2;i++)` to synchronize that element, but it never worked as it should. When each process is executed once, everything works fine.
MainProcess3args.cpp

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
HANDLE hMutex; //used mutex object to implement spinlock
using namespace std;
SYSTEM_INFO siSysInfo;
int main(int argc, TCHAR *argv[])  
{  
   STARTUPINFO si1 = { 0 }, si2 = { 0 };
    si1.cb = sizeof si1;
    si2.cb = sizeof si2;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi1 = { 0 }, pi2 = { 0 };
    const TCHAR* target1 = _T("C:\\USERS\\Admin\\Documents\\Random3args.exe");
    const TCHAR* target2 = _T("C:\\USERS\\Admin\\Documents\\ReadingRandoms3args.exe");
    
    fstream Results;
    Results.open("Results.txt", ios::in | ios::out);
    if (!Results.is_open())
    cerr << "failed to open file\n";
    GetSystemInfo(&siSysInfo);
    int n = 0;//first argument, defines, how many files needs to be generated
    int times=0;//second argument,defines time distance beetween generating numbers
    int repeat = 0;//third argument
    n=_tstoi(argv[1]);
    times=_tstoi(argv[2]);
    repeat=_tstoi(argv[3]);
    Results<<"Total numbers: "<<n<<" | Version:Multithreads | Machine: OEM ID: "<<siSysInfo.dwOemId<<" Processor Type: "<<siSysInfo.dwProcessorType<<" | Replies: "<<repeat<<" | Pause: "<<times;
    times=times/0.001;
    
    hMutex = CreateMutex(NULL,0,NULL);
    //for(int i=0;i<repeat;i++){
   if (!CreateProcess(target1, GetCommandLine(), 0, FALSE, 0, CREATE_SUSPENDED, 0, 0, &si1, &pi1)) //CREATE_SUSPENDED argument makes process 1 hanging and waiting until process 2 excecute
    {
        cerr << "CreateProcess failed (" << GetLastError() << ").\n";
    }
    else
    {
        
         WaitForSingleObject(hMutex,INFINITE);  // process2 call WaitForSingleObject(hmutex) first to get mutex
        
        if (!CreateProcess(target2, 0, 0, FALSE, 0, 0, 0, 0, &si2, &pi2))//Process 2 is created and excecuted ...
        {
            cerr << "CreateProcess failed (" << GetLastError() << ").\n";
        }
        else
        {
            WaitForSingleObject(pi2.hProcess, INFINITE);
            
            CloseHandle(pi2.hProcess); //process2 closes
            CloseHandle(pi2.hThread);
        }
    
        ReleaseMutex(hMutex);//mutex released, process1 unlocked
        ResumeThread(pi1.hThread); //Process 1 is resumed and executed 
        WaitForSingleObject(pi1.hProcess, INFINITE);
    
        CloseHandle(hMutex);
        CloseHandle(pi1.hProcess);//process 1 closes
        CloseHandle(pi1.hThread);
 
    }
    LARGE_INTEGER li;
    double PCFreq = 0.0;
    __int64 CounterStart = 0; 
    if(!QueryPerformanceFrequency(&li))
    cout << "QueryPerformanceFrequency failed!\n";

    PCFreq = double(li.QuadPart)/1000.0;

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);
    CounterStart = li.QuadPart;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);
    double c= (li.QuadPart - CounterStart)/PCFreq;
    cout<<"Performance time: "<<c<< " miliseconds";
    
    Results.close();
    cin.sync();
    cin.ignore();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

First process - Random3args.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
SYSTEM_INFO siSysInfo;
int main( int argc, TCHAR *argv[] )
{
    fstream File;
    File.open("RandomValues.txt", ios::in | ios::out);
    if (!File.is_open())
    cerr << "failed to open file\n";
    srand( time( NULL ) );
    
    int n = 0;//first argument, defines, how many files needs to be generated
    int times=0;//second argument,defines time distance beetween generating numbers
    int repeat = 0;//third argument
    n=_tstoi(argv[1]);
    times=_tstoi(argv[2]);
    repeat=_tstoi(argv[3]);
    times=times/0.001;
    
    int r=0;
    cout<<endl;
    for(int j=0;j<repeat;j++)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        r=rand() % 100;
        File<<r<<" ";
        cout<<r<<"values "; //checking if values are read correctly
        
    }
    cout<<endl;
     Sleep(times);
    }
    
    File.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Second Process - ReadingRandoms3args.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
//this program calculates average value of numbers in file, finds minimum and maximum in the file using 3 threads
#define THREADCOUNT 3
using namespace std;
HANDLE hSemaphore; // using semaphore object to synchronize threads
vector<int> Values;
double Average,MIN,MAX;


DWORD Averages(LPVOID* arg)  
{  
      
      WaitForSingleObject(hSemaphore, INFINITE); 
      Average = 0;
      double Sum = 0;
      //for(int j=0;j<repeat;j++)
      
      for (unsigned int i = 0; i < Values.size(); i++) { 
    //cout << Values[i] << " "; checking, if the values from the file are being read correctly
       Sum+=Values[i];
       }
      Average = Sum/Values.size();
    cout<<"The average of given values is: "<<Average<<endl; 

    ReleaseSemaphore(hSemaphore,1,NULL);
    return 0;
}  
DWORD Minimum(LPVOID* arg)  
{  
       
     WaitForSingleObject(hSemaphore, INFINITE); 
     MIN=Values[0];
     for(unsigned int j=0;j<Values.size();j++)
     {
        if(MIN>Values[j])
        {
        MIN=Values[j];
        }
}
cout<<endl;
cout<<"Minimum value is "<<MIN<<endl;  
      ReleaseSemaphore(hSemaphore,1,NULL);
    return 0;
}  
DWORD Maximum(LPVOID* arg)  
{  
    
    WaitForSingleObject(hSemaphore, INFINITE);
     MAX=Values[0];
     for(unsigned int k=0;k<Values.size();k++)
    {
       if(MAX<Values[k])
        {
        MAX=Values[k];
        }
    }
cout<<endl;
cout<<"Maximum value is "<<MAX<<endl;  
      ReleaseSemaphore(hSemaphore,1,NULL);  
    return 0;
}  
int main( int argc, TCHAR *argv[] )
{
// open the file
ifstream File("RandomValues.txt", ios::in);
if (!File.is_open())
    cerr << "failed to open file\n";
  
// read the values 
int val;

while (File >> val){
    Values.push_back(val);
   
   }
fstream Results;
Results.open("Results.txt", ios::in | ios::out);
if (!Results.is_open())
    cerr << "failed to open file\n";
int repeat = _tstoi(argv[3]) ;   
//cout<<repeat;
Results<<"AVG  "<<"MIN  "<<"MAX  "<<endl;  
  
hSemaphore=CreateSemaphore(NULL,0,3,NULL); 
HANDLE hThreads[3];  
DWORD threadID1,threadID2,threadID3; 

for(int i=0;i<repeat;i++){
        // calculate average of values-first thread
hThreads[0]=CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)Averages, &hSemaphore,0, &threadID1);

// finding minimum - second thread
hThreads[1]=CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)Minimum, &hSemaphore, 0, &threadID2);
// finding maximum - third thread
hThreads[2]=CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)Maximum, &hSemaphore, 0, &threadID3);
}

ReleaseSemaphore(hSemaphore,1,NULL);  
WaitForMultipleObjects(THREADCOUNT, hThreads, TRUE, INFINITE);  
for( int i=0; i < THREADCOUNT; i++ ){

        CloseHandle(hThreads[i]);
    }
CloseHandle(hSemaphore);  
Results<<Average<<"  "<<MIN<<"  "<<MAX<<endl;
File.close();
Results.close();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You've told us what you want and posted a bunch of code but not told us how what you are getting is different from what you want.

Comment: Hi
I shared that bunch of code to clarify the situation and how it looks like.
The results which I am getting right now,is only part about system info saved in file with Results. I have tried to use loop in the MainProcess file,which executes  processes as long as iteration variable is equal to repeat parameter. 
I tried as well to ran each threads from ReadingRandoms file using The same loop,but it ran threads in wrong order.

Comment: Where in the code do you impose any ordering on the thread execution?

Comment: I have commented this fragment in the MainProcess file, as this loop didn't worked correctly - it ran the processes in right order, but did not saved system info and results right to Result.txt file

Comment: The loop is  ```for(int i=0;i<repeat;i++){ excecuting processes```}

Comment: Your question starts with "multiple threads" but then you continue with multiple processes. Your code isn't formatted consistently either, so I'm not really motivated to even read it but it also makes it harder to understand, even for the author. Please [edit] your question to make it more consistent and generally improve it. Comments should not contain relevant parts! As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: I understand, that it sound complicated - basically the problem is related to multiple threads and two processes. Although, thanks for answer, will edit question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Process2 should always run first, and that part works ok.`

There is an error here. When you suspend `Process1` in `MainProcess3args.cpp` and execute `Process2` first, `Process2` cannot read any data, so you should execute `Process1` first, and then read through Process1.

The following code:

```
const TCHAR* target1 = _T("C:\\USERS\\Admin\\Documents\\Random3args.exe");
const TCHAR* target2 = _T("C:\\USERS\\Admin\\Documents\\ReadingRandoms3args.exe");
...
CreateProcess(target1, GetCommandLine(), 0, FALSE, 0, CREATE_SUSPENDED, 0, 0, &si1, &pi1);
...
CreateProcess(target2, GetCommandLine(), 0, FALSE, 0, 0, 0, 0, &si2, &pi2);
...
```

Just modify to:

```
const TCHAR* target1 = _T("C:\\USERS\\Admin\\Documents\\ReadingRandoms3args.exe");
const TCHAR* target2 = _T("C:\\USERS\\Admin\\Documents\\Random3args.exe");
...
CreateProcess(target1, GetCommandLine(), 0, FALSE, 0, CREATE_SUSPENDED, 0, 0, &si1, &pi1);
...
CreateProcess(target2, GetCommandLine(), 0, FALSE, 0, 0, 0, 0, &si2, &pi2);
...
```

This ensures that `Process2` that reads data is suspended first, and the process of generating random data is executed first.

There are some minor problems in the source code. In `MainProcess3args.cpp`, when you finish writing:

```
Results << "Total numbers: " << n << " | Version:Multithreads | Machine: OEM ID: " << siSysInfo.dwOemId << " Processor Type: " << siSysInfo.dwProcessorType << " | Replies: " << repeat << " | Pause: " << times;
```

After this, you did not write to the file, but your `Process2` needs to open the file handle to write the result. At this time, you have not closed the file handle (you closed it at the end of the main process).

So you need to close the file handle after the main process writes and before creating `Process2`. Such as the following code:

```
Results << "Total numbers: " << n << " | Version:Multithreads | Machine: OEM ID: " << siSysInfo.dwOemId << " Processor Type: " << siSysInfo.dwProcessorType << " | Replies: " << repeat << " | Pause: " << times;
Results.close();
```

Finally it works for me:

[image]

**Edit:**

Both `CreateProcess` need to pass `GetCommandLine()` parameter, otherwise the program will cras when calling argv[3].I have changed my code.

Else, you can use the following code to output:

```
ofstream Results;
Results.open("Results.txt", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);
if (!Results.is_open())
    cerr << "failed to open file\n";
int repeat = _tstoi(argv[3]);
//cout<<repeat;
Results << endl;
Results << "AVG  " << "MIN  " << "MAX  " << endl;
```

In this way, the output content can be appended to `Result.txt` instead of overwriting the original content.

There are also some resource leakage issues:

```
for (int i = 0; i < repeat; i++) {
// calculate average of values-first thread
hThreads[0] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)Averages, &hSemaphore, 0, &threadID1);
// finding minimum - second thread
hThreads[1] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)Minimum, &hSemaphore, 0, &threadID2);
// finding maximum - third thread
hThreads[2] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)Maximum, &hSemaphore, 0, &threadID3);
}
```

When repeat is greater than 1, running the above code will cause the previous `hThreads`handle to be overwritten, and save the last created thread handle. It is necessary to ensure that the thread handle is closed normally after each loop.

Comment: Hi :) Thank you for your answer. At this moment I do not have access to my laptop, will check it after work and answer :)

Comment: modified code as above, ran it and it shows only output from first suspended process "ReadingRandoms". I try to make a output in command line like "ReadingRandoms" results and "Random" results shown within argv[2] time distance and argv[3] times. That's why I tried first with loop which repeats excecuting processes with argv[3] times.

Comment: I came up with idea to write info about system and threads results  to results file through process2 Source file,although this method as well is not executing process2.

Comment: @wiki11ful I edited my answer and there are some code suggestions for your reference.

Comment: I can see your comment now @Zhu Song and I've aready managed to save all content that is needed to the file. I moved this part of a code to ReadingRandoms file and it works now :)

Comment: marked your answer as resolved :) thank you for help :)